# EventArgs VS GridViewRowEventArgs

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to access the button click event from my asp.net gridview.  If I leave my syntax like so

```
protected void Remove(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Their is no compile error but I get a debug error.  of

> No overload for '' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Well if I change my syntax to this

```
protected void Remove(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var command = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;            
  if (command.CommandName == "Remove")
  {
    DataGridItem gr = (DataGridItem)command.NamingContainer;
    string abcd = gr.Cells[0].Text;
  }
}
```

I get multiple compile errorrs of:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'CommandName' and no extension method 'CommandName' accepting a first argument of type 'string' 
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'NamingContainer' and no extension method 'NamingContainer' accepting a first argument of type 'string' 
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What I want to do is from the button press event in my grid view access the value and run a stored procedure.

And here is the aspx markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwEditDashboard" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" CssClass="DataGrids"
Width="500px" HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="Both" >
<Columns> 
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID = "btnDelete" runat = "server" CssClass="ButtonLink"  Text = "[Delete]" OnClick = "Remove" />
</ItemTemplate>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, understand that [**`GridViewRowEventArgs`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewroweventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is meant for events: [**`RowCreated`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**`RowDataBound`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx). These events are not a button click event.

Secondly, when the LinkButton is clicked, there are possibly two events raised: [**`LinkButton.Click`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [**`GridView.RowCommand`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

My advice is to use/handle the [**`RowCommand`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of GridView.

There are many techniques to get the data of the Row where the button was clicked inside this event.

Specifically to your situation, declare the LinkButton as :

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID = "btnDelete" runat = "server"
       CssClass="ButtonLink"  Text = "[Delete]" OnClick = "Remove" 
       CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Notice the `CommandArgument` property of LinkButton.

And the RowCommand event. Notice that the second param is [**`GridViewCommandEventArgs`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        // The RowIndex of the Row where LinkButton was clicked
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        // Get the GridView Row
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];

        // Read the Column values
        // e.g. for BoundFields use row.Cells[] 
        string Column_1_Value = row.Cells[0].Text;

        // for Columns defined using <itemTemplate> etc...
        // row.FindControl("<Control_ID>")
        string firstName = (row.FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox).Text;
}
```

Alternative to LinkButton, you can use [**`ButtonFields`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well. Check the row command event at this link. The MSDN sample explains nicely on reading rows data.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Remove(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var command = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;            
   if (command.CommandName == "Remove")
   {
     DataGridItem gr = (DataGridItem)command.NamingContainer;
     string abcd = gr.Cells[0].Text;
   }
 }
```

The hazards of var. CommandArgument is of type string on a button. You're getting that error because string has no CommandName or NamingContainer property.

Try the following:

```
protected void Remove(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{         
   if (e.CommandName == "Remove")
   {
     DataGridItem gr = e.NamingContainer;
     string abcd = gr.Cells[0].Text;
   }
 }
```

Comment: this presents a compile error of CommandEventArgs does not contain a definition for NamingContainer

Comment: Ah. Right you are. What do you want to get the naming container from? ((Button.sender) will have a NamingContainer, but that may not be the naming container you want.

Comment: I want to capture the value of gr.Cells[0].Text - or the Text in the 1st column of the row where the button was pressed.